# Gridlayout Not Sizing to Constraints

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jbutton

```
    this.setSize(700,500);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setIconImage(frameIcon.getImage());
    this.setTitle("Rifle Reload Logger v1.0");
    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(700,500));
     /*
    * The center panel of the JFrame will be used to display the current information
    * as needed whether it be for showing the file chooser, or the reload data.*/
    center.setVisible(true);
    center.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,4));
    this.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setGUILabels();//sets the labels for the entire Gui.
```

Essentially my problem here is my GridLayout does not create the 6x4 size that I am asking it to. it goes to a 6x3 size, here is an image. [Improper gridlayout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOYB5.png)

Comment: There's very likely a bug somewhere else in your program in code not shown. You will want to create and post a [minimal, compilable, runnable example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to tell you why you're experiencing this misbehavior.

Comment: Edit: you've only added 18 components to your center JPanel, not 24. If you want 4 columns and a variable number of rows, set GridLayout to `new GridLayout(0, 4)`.

Comment: I will try doing a variable row size, that should work perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only added 18 components to your center JPanel, not 24. If you want 4 columns and a variable number of rows, set GridLayout to `new GridLayout(0, 4)`.